# Laravel Entrust change table name

Tags: php, laravel, entrust

I'm using laravel 5.2 multi auth so I have created a new management table instead of user table.

I have installed Entrust for roles and permissions. During the entrust installation, I have changed entrust:migration content as:

```php
public function up()
{
    // Create table for storing roles
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('display_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    // Create table for associating roles to users (Many-to-Many)
    Schema::create('role_management', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('management_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('management_id')->references('id')->on('managements')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['management_id', 'role_id']);
    });

    // Create table for storing permissions
    Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('display_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    // Create table for associating permissions to roles (Many-to-Many)
    Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
    });
}
```

and `entrust.php` as:

```php
return [
'role' => 'App\Role',
'roles_table' => 'roles',
'permission' => 'App\Permission',
'role_user_table' => 'role_management',
];
```

and I have 3 models, Role and Permission and Management. Everything works fine, but the problem is when I want to attachRoles into the `role_management` table with code below:

```php
public function store(userManagementFormRequest $request)
{
    $user=new Management(array(
        'name'=>$request->get('name'),
        'password'=>bcrypt($request->get('password')),
    ));
    $user->save();
    $user->attachRoles($_POST['role']);
    return redirect()->back()->with('userStatus','عملیات با موفقیت انجام گردید.');
}
```

it will show an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'digikala.management_role' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `management_role` (`created_at`, `management_id`, `role_id`, `updated_at`) values (2016-03-21 14:26:24, 1, 1, 2016-03-21 14:26:24))

I don't know why it shows `management_role` instead of `role_management`, while the right table name is `role_management`. Also, I have just two columns, `management_id` and `role_id`, in this table, but also in this error it wants to insert `created_at` and `updated_at` into this table.

I have used composer config:cache and composer cache:clear and compose dump-autoload but nothing happened.

Is there anything wrong in my code?
management model:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;

class Management extends Authenticatable
{
use EntrustUserTrait;
protected $table='managements';
protected $fillable=['name','password'];
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withTimestamps();
}
}
```

Comment: Can I see your management model?

Comment: i've added my management model.

Comment: the roles function does not have any relation to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to override the `roles` relationship function. It already exists in the `EntrustUserTrait`.

You can remove it and it should work.

Comment: but also you have to change user_id to management_id in EntrustUserTrai.php

Comment: You can configure it by adding `'user_foreign_key' => 'management_id'` into the array in `app/config/entrust.php`